# "showmount: command not found": how do I know what to install?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, package-management, kali-linux

Sometimes you run a command and get a "command not found" error message.

After that you try to install the package that contains that command (I think that's what happens anyway?)

e.g. `showmount: command not found`

`apt-get install showmount` does nothing, so I guess the `showmount` command is part of a package, but I don't know what that package is.

How can I find out what package I need to install to get whichever command I need? I am using Kali Linux.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use apt-cache, which is included as default on debian based distributions (afaik):

```
apt-cache search showmount
```

which gives the result nfs-common as well.

Comment: That works in this case (and is a good idea anyway), but it only finds words mentioned in a package’s name and description, so it’s unfortunately not applicable generally.

Comment: In Debian can work also like `apt search pkgname`

Comment: @StephenKitt Correct!

Comment: both apt-cache search showmount and apt search showmount have me the result i was looking for. 
@StephenKitt when i use apt-file search showmount it says update cache despite already running apt-file update. That is why i have asked Joakims answer.

Comment: That’s fine, I hope you don’t mind that I edited your question to make its title more specific as a result (since the accepted answer doesn’t work in general).

Answer (score 32):

You can use `apt-file` for that (you might need to install it):

```
apt-file search showmount
```

This reveals that the command is in the `nfs-common` package.

Typically when you're looking for a binary you can restrict the search by prefixing the binary with `bin/`:

```
apt-file search bin/showmount
```

To install `apt-file`, run

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

If you end up with `apt-file` 3.0 or later, you won’t need to update the indexes again separately (after the initial download above), they are updated whenever the main APT indexes are updated.

Answer (score 20):

You might want to ease your life by installing the [command-not-found helper](http://packages.debian.org/command-not-found)

```
$ sudo apt install command-not-found
[…]
$ showmount
Command 'showmount' is available in '/sbin/showmount'
The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative priviledges associated with your user account.
showmount: command not found
```

Comment: Nice, but note that this works in `bash` but not in other shells (I tried `tcsh` and `zsh`)

Answer (score 1):

Browse over to http://packages.debian.org or http://packages.ubuntu.com under the 'Search the contents of packages' section. You can find the package that contains the file you need without installing other apt tools.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while mounting nfs server. In my case just run the following command.

```
sudo showmount -e [ip address of the nfs server]
```

I forgot to write sudo.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands,

- `# apt update`
- `# apt install rpcbind nfs-common`